# Android Studio Rendering Library

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

I just created `Test` project inside of `Android Studio` and I'm getting following message:

Summary:

> Rendering Problems: This version of the rendering library is more
>   recent than your version of Android Studio. Please update Android
>   Studio.

Details:

```
org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.RenderingException: This version of the rendering library is more recent than your version of Android Studio. Please update Android Studio
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.LayoutLibraryLoader.load(LayoutLibraryLoader.java:90)
    at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidTargetData.getLayoutLibrary(AndroidTargetData.java:159)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.createTask(RenderService.java:164)
    at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$6.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:475)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:351)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Yet my `Android Studio` *IS* up to date, as I check it via `Help` -> `Check for Update` and I get `Your already have the latest version of Android Studio installed.`

Comment: That's weird... can you post your app build.gradle?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Ahh, I found that `Preview Android Versions` should be changed from `API 22: Android M (Preview)` to any Non-Preview Android Version.

[image]

Comment: I think one picture is more than 1000s words, so I added screenshot to your answer, for a record...

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski thank you for including screenshot)

Comment: Thanks for the picture. Helped a lot.

Comment: Thanks a lot alexus, you're a star

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed now with the latest update 1.2.2.

[image]

http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio122nowavailable