# This version of the rendering library is more recent than your version of ADT plug-in. Please update ADT plug-in - already updated

Tags: android, sdk

on eclipse - i'm getting this error although i'm on the latest adt version. im not sure it's related but this happened right after i installed android-m sdk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30535515/933050

Change API version to 22 instead of M Preview

**For Android Studio :** 
[image]

**For Eclipse :**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem this way :

- in the sdk manager, I added the sdk of an older platform, for example, being myself in the version 24 (v7), I loaded in addition the old 17 version (4.2.2).
- this old 17 version becomes then available in the layout designer, (upper right) (after reopening eclipse)
- choosing it instead of the 24 one solves the problem

In fact, with this old version, the "rendering library" here version 17, becomes "strongly" less recent thant de ADT (that must be something like 22, 23 or 24).

Surely, a more recent version of the platform, say perhaps 22, would do as well and even better than the 17. To try.

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 options:

update or install new software : Go to `Help >> Install new software` and add install `https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/` then select Developer Tools and click on next to begin install.

or

Change the API version in XML.