# This version of the rendering library is more recent than your version of Android Studio. Please update Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

I have just created new project in android studio. I am new with this tool.
The problem is, it is not displaying me my design, It giving me error that,

```
This version of the rendering library is more recent than your version of Android Studio. Please update Android Studio
```

I research on it, and by reading this question I do the same [Android Studio Rendering Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30535456/android-studio-rendering-library])[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rjioq.png)

But now, I am getting java compilation errors in MainActivity.java file.

[image]

[image]

Do I need to import any library ?

Comment: No, you don't need anything, just select 22(5.1.1) Don't select M(Preview) And restart Android Studio. Same case with me, and solved it like this.

Comment: I select 23 and refresh preview window. It worked for me :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My problem was solved by changing my current android version to **API 22 Android 5.1.1** 
This video helped me get through the error 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=49CF6uU38Wo

Comment: I have already set it API 22 Android 5.1.1. But It is giving me same error and second error I am getting is "aidl is missing"

Comment: Go to app > Right Click on it > Open Module Settings>Change build tool version to 22.0.1

Comment: Hey that works, Now I am able to build my project. You can write as separate answer, I will make it right :)

Comment: But when I execute my project, it giving me error 
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!..... 
I am using nexus 5 api 22 from dropdown

Comment: Start your SDK  manager and install HAXM from there.

Comment: Hey dude... Again solved... :) (Y) 
Thanks a lot