# Rendering problems for Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, rendering

Since yesterday I have start to working with Android studio. My problem is when I make my layout. I've next error *(watch the screenshot for more information)*:

> **Rendering Problem:** This version of the rendering library is more recent than your version of Android Studio. Please update Android Studio

[image: Problem]

If I check for updates he say that I already have the latest version of Android studio and so I can't update.

[image: no updates]

I have also install some things in the SDK manager, see screenshot below.

[image: SDK manager]

Can anyone help me to fix this problem? 
Thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30535456/android-studio-rendering-library

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same problem, current update, but rendering failed because I need to update.

Try changing the update version you are on. The default is Stable, but there are 3 more options, Canary being the newest and potentially least stable. I chose to check for updates from the Dev Channel, which is a little more stable than Canary build. It fixed the problem and seems to work fine.

To change the version, Check for Updates, then click the Updates link on the popup that says you already have the latest version.

Good luck in the class!

Comment: Yes, I updated to the beta build (version 1.2.2) just now and the layout rendering works again. it's very unfortunate that things break when they update the tools.

Answer (score 7):

This issue has been fixed now with the latest update 1.2.2 from stable channel, so no need to install beta or canary versions.

[image]
<sup>Click on image to view more information</sup>